# Finding elements by Class returning blank list

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I have a code to pull the vessels from this website:

'https://signal.portoptimizer.com/'

I was able to open the table with the vessels using

```
arrow_icon = self.driver.find_element('xpath','/html/body/app-root/app-pure-frame/div/div/div/app-signal2-page/div/div/app-current-inbound-vessels/div/app-widget-card/div/div[2]/div/mat-expansion-panel/mat-expansion-panel-header/span[2]')
arrow_icon.click()
```

but now I want to have a list with all vessesls, tried with the below but it is showing no value in the list:

```
all_vessels = self.driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"anchorage-by-terminal")
print(all_vessels)
```

What would be the issue?

Comment: this class doesn't exist, as far as I can tell?

Comment: I tried getting the vessel name ARISTOMENIS, is this not the class? <span _ngcontent-bfx-c180="" elem="cell-content" class="anchorage-by-terminal-table-cell-content ng-star-inserted">ARISTOMENIS</span> @JoshFriedlander

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the the vessel names as following:
First get all the table rows and then get each row first cell text, like this:

```py
rows = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"datatable-row-wrapper datatable-body-row")
for row in row:
    name = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.anchorage-by-terminal-table-cell-content").text
    print(name)
```

`"span.anchorage-by-terminal-table-cell-content"` is not a unique locator for the first cell in the row, but since we are looking for a first call in each row this will work here.
Also, don't forget using delays, preferably expected conditions explicit waits to make page / elements loaded before you access them.
**UPD**
In order to get non-first cell content you will have to mention the explicit matching locator index.
For example to get Expected date of Berth you can do this:

```py
rows = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"datatable-row-wrapper datatable-body-row")
for row in row:
    berth = row.find_element(By.XPATH,"(.//span[contains(@class,'pure-frame-cell-content')])[3]").text
    print(berth)
```

Pay attention, these cells having different class name but it is not unique too

Comment: Hello Prophet, first, thank you very much for your answer. However I am a bit confused about this solutions and had trouble implementing it to bring the next column (Expected date of Berth). Should it not be span.pure-frame-cell-content?

Comment: ` span.pure-frame-cell-content` matching several cell in each row. I'' update my answer

Comment: See the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You want to find a class given only part of the name (in this case the beginning). You can do this with CSS selectors:

```
self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='anchorage-by-terminal']")
```

More generally, you can find an element with an attribute starting with some text with

```
self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element[attribute^='start-text']")
```

Ending with some text as:

```
self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element[attribute$='end-text']")
```

And containing some text as:

```
self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element[attribute*='anywhere-text']")
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the **Vessel Names** from the [website](https://signal.portoptimizer.com/) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and using [*List Slising*](https://theprogrammingexpert.com/python-every-nth-element-in-list/) you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://signal.portoptimizer.com/'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//mat-panel-title[normalize-space()='Click to view inbound vessels']"))).click()
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.anchorage-by-terminal-table-cell-content")))[::4]])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://signal.portoptimizer.com/'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//mat-panel-title[normalize-space()='Click to view inbound vessels']"))).click()
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'anchorage-by-terminal-table-cell-content')]")))[::4]])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['CMA CGM PANAMA', 'ARISTOMENIS', 'CMA CGM DIGNITY', 'MSC ARIANE', 'YM UBIQUITY', 'MAERSK EUREKA', 'MSC SAVONA', 'CMA CGM SYMI', 'YM TUTORIAL']
  ```